# Make a filter to one color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I tried to make a function to detect some word from browser. My current solution is take the screenshot in location where the text can appear.

```
 im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1229, 11, 1233, 20))
     im = im.convert('1')
     pixels = im.getdata()
```

But, it work with only small picture what capture by `grab` function. And, the text i want to detect have an unique color. So, have anyway to make a filter can make all diffrent colors disappear and show only white and that text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtering on each point of image using the code below:

```
output = pixels.point(lambda x: 1 if x==REQUIREDCOLOR else 0, '1')
```

Comment: is the value `x==REQUIREDCOLOR ` hexa?

Comment: whichever value your pixel is after converting it to using `im.convert('1')`